# Adding function parameters using a single variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, html

I was thinking the is it possible to pass a variable to function which is to be executed on clicking the button and the function is given by a variable.

Also the parameters of the functions could be more than one and so I separated them by `,`.

So is there a way that I can put the parameters into function using any jQuery plugin or a function. Please help me out, cause I'm confuse big time! Here is my current jQuery Code:

```
function Func (a,b){
 alert(a+' | '+b);   
}
var Parameters = 'cool,123';
var Function = Func;

$('button').click(Function);
```

[Problem demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6nJx7/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
function Func (a,b){
 alert(a+' | '+b);   
}
var Parameters = 'cool,123';

$('button').click(function() {
    Func.apply(this, Parameters.split(","));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6nJx7/14/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply

Comment: This is the best answer! And it has won the Jack Pot!

Comment: The only problem is that you can't pass objects/functions as arguments, only strings which will get automatically typecast to numbers when needed.

Comment: @DarthJDG - this is true. I would have preferred if he had accepted your answer, I posted this when you had deleted your initial answer, and before you undeleted.

Comment: No problem, I'm not complaining because of that, I just thought I'd mention. It happened to me enough times too that I was just about to post an answer when the message popped up that someone else beat me to it. Annoying that is, but sometimes I just submit anyway. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `function.apply()`. Pass your list of parameters in as an array and you can even set a scope if you wish to do so:

```
function myFunc(a,b){
    alert(a+", "+b);
}

var args = ["one", "two"];
var func = myFunc;

$('button').click(function(){
    func.apply(this, args);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass your parameters as an array ..

```
 function Func (a){
     alert(a[0]+' | '+a[1]);   
    }
    var Parameters = new Array(0,1);
    var Function = Func;

    $('button').click(Function(Parameters));
```

Comment: Thanks but the function is loading itself on refreshing the document! Any suggestions? http://jsfiddle.net/divinemamgai/MMqM5/

Comment: That won't work.  You'd wind up calling Function(Parameters) immediately, since it is isn't wrapped as a closure.  You'd want something more like '$('button').click(function(){Function(Parameters)});' -- However, the 'apply' suggestion below will be more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it, I like this better myself because it is somewhat self documenting.  Each of the "parameters" in the options list has a name.

This is a common design pattern in JavaScript libraries for options to a module.

```
function Func (c){
 alert(c.a+' | '+c.b);   
}
var Parameters = { a : "cool", b: 123 };
var Function = Func;

$('button').click(Parameters );
```